# sql server - trigger with cursor

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursor

I am trying to design a landing table that will receive order lines and then a trigger will send the data to the appropriate tables (i.e. customer, order, order line).

I was easily able to do this in MySQL with the new and old key words however I am having some issues in SQL Server.

Firstly - is this the best approach for this type of problem?

Secondly if it is I have tried to create a trigger which uses a cursor to iterate through the inserted table in SQL Server. unfortunately I keep getting an error

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _raw_b2c_lines_ins, Line 17 [Batch Start Line 6]
>   A cursor with the name 'ins_cusor' does not exist

I have attached the code below (removed code for the order and order line table to simplify)

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER zap._raw_b2c_lines_ins
            on zap._b2c
            after insert
            as
            begin

            declare @v_phone_cleansed varchar
            ,   @phone varchar
            ,   @v_curr_cust_id varchar
            ,   @customer_key varchar
            ,   @t_order_id int
            ,   @customer_id varchar
            ,   @t_raw_id int
            --
            declare ins_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT t_raw_id from inserted;
            --

            OPEN ins_cusor;

            FETCH NEXT from ins_cursor INTO @t_raw_id;

            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            --
            BEGIN

            set @v_phone_cleansed = dbo.CleanNumber((select billing_phone 
            from    inserted 
            where   t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            ));
            set @v_curr_cust_id = (select  isnull(max(t_customer_id),0) +1 from sales.b2c_customer);
            --
            if exists(  select  1 
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) =        lower(i.billing_email)
            and     (   lower(c.country) != lower(i.billing_country)
            or  lower(c.city) !=    lower(i.billing_city)
            or  c.phone_cleansed != @v_phone_cleansed   
            )
            and     c.current_record = 1
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id  ) 
            --
            Begin
            set @customer_key = (   select  top 1 customer_key
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) =        lower(i.billing_email)
            and     (   lower(c.country)!=  lower(i.billing_country)
            or  lower(c.city) !=    lower(i.billing_city)
            or  c.phone_cleansed != @v_phone_cleansed   
            )
            and     c.current_record = 1    
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            );
            --
            update sales.b2c_customer 
            set current_record = 0 
            where   exists (select  *
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) =        lower(i.billing_email)
            and     (   lower(c.country) != lower(i.billing_country)
            or  lower(c.city) !=    lower(i.billing_city)
            or  c.phone_cleansed != @v_phone_cleansed
            )
            and     c.current_record = 1
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            )

            insert into sales.b2c_customer(
            customer_key
            ,   last_name
            ,   first_name
            ,   email
            ,   country
            ,   city
            ,   phone
            ,   phone_cleansed
            ,   current_record
            ) select    @customer_key
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_last_name)
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_first_name)
            ,   i.billing_email
            ,   i.billing_country
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_city)
            ,   i.billing_phone
            ,   @v_phone_cleansed
            ,   1
            from    inserted i
            where   i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            ;
            --
            end
            --
            if exists(  select  1 
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) !=       lower(i.billing_email)
            and     lower(c.country) =      lower(i.billing_country)
            and     lower(c.city) =         lower(i.billing_city)
            and     lower(c.phone_cleansed) =   @v_phone_cleansed
            and     current_record = 1
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            ) 
            --
            Begin
            --
            set     @customer_key = (   select  top 1 customer_key
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i 
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) !=       lower(i.billing_email)
            and     lower(c.country) =      lower(i.billing_country)
            and     lower(c.city) =         lower(i.billing_city)
            and     c.phone_cleansed =  @v_phone_cleansed
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            );
            update sales.b2c_customer 
            set current_record = 0 
            where   exists (select  *
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) !=       lower(i.billing_email)
            and     lower(c.country) =  lower(i.billing_country)
            and     lower(c.city) =     lower(i.billing_city)
            and     c.phone_cleansed =  @v_phone_cleansed
            and     c.current_record = 1
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            )


            insert into sales.b2c_customer(
            customer_key
            ,   last_name
            ,   first_name
            ,   email
            ,   country
            ,   city
            ,   phone
            ,   phone_cleansed
            ,   current_record
            )   select  @customer_key
            ,       dbo.InitCap(i.billing_last_name)
            ,       dbo.InitCap(i.billing_first_name)
            ,       i.billing_email
            ,       i.billing_country
            ,       dbo.InitCap(i.billing_city)
            ,       i.billing_phone
            ,       @v_phone_cleansed
            ,       1
            from    inserted i
            where   i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            --
            end
            --                    
            if not exists (
            select  1 
            from    sales.b2c_customer c
            join    inserted i 
            on      lower(c.first_name) =   lower(i.billing_first_name)
            and     lower(c.last_name) =    lower(i.billing_last_name)
            and     lower(c.email) =        lower(i.billing_email)
            and     lower(c.country) =      lower(i.billing_country)
            and     lower(c.city) =         lower(i.billing_city)
            and     c.phone_cleansed =  @v_phone_cleansed
            and     c.current_record = 1
            and     i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id
            ) 
            --
            Begin
            --
            insert into sales.b2c_customer( customer_key
            ,   last_name
            ,   first_name
            ,   email
            ,   country
            ,   city
            ,   phone
            ,   phone_cleansed
            ,   current_record
            )   select concat(lower(i.billing_first_name), lower(i.billing_last_name), @v_curr_cust_id)
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_last_name)
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_first_name)
            ,   i.billing_email
            ,   i.billing_country
            ,   dbo.InitCap(i.billing_city)
            ,   i.billing_phone
            ,   @v_phone_cleansed
            ,   1
            from inserted i 
            where i.t_raw_id = @t_raw_id;
            --
            end 
            --

            FETCH NEXT from ins_cursor INTO @t_raw_id;

            end

            close ins_cursor; 
            deallocate ins_cursor;
            end
```

Comment: so i spotted the spelling mistake...  which is why im getting the error... my bad

any comments on first question? is the best approach for what I would like to achieve?

Comment: type `OPEN ins_cursor;` instead of `OPEN ins_cusor;`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Otherwise, you end up with SQL variables that are **exactly ONE character long** - typically *not* what you want.....

Comment: Oh my, cursor in a trigger! Why you need to iterate through rows? You can use `inserted` to merge tables you need.

Comment: Is this the best approach? That is a question that cannot be accurately evaluated without a good understanding of your schema and the reasons that led you to this "solution". Offhand, I would say no. But that is a pure guess. And writing triggers is difficult in sql server - this is not something for those without experience in tsql and without the proper mindset. Triggers in sql server execute at a batch level and must handle any number of rows generated by the triggering statememt.

Comment: Hi thanks all for your help. Basically I want to have a table that acts as a landing table where i insert data (or it comes from automation like zapier) - and then this data is processed into the appropriate tables (simply a customer, order and order line table) - I have managed to get this to work but still dont know if it is the best way to do this?? any ideas?

Comment: OMG Malainine - even looking at your comment I took me a while to see that typo.  That was a sneaky one!

Answer (score -1):

first create procedure in that name then execute
because it cant find that cursor.